# setError function in android not displaying full error message

Tags: android

I am getting a weird issue, when I am adding message using `setError` function with a long email id in edit text field, and that too this issue is coming in small size tablets like 7 inch, no problem coming in 10 inch device.

This issue is coming in emulator as well. I have set a long 46 character email id for testing purposes, and showing that email id via `setError` function when email id edit text is not editable, but this email id is not being shown correctly, instead some characters from end are getting cut off.

When I tried to remove '@' or '.' (dot) from that email id, and replace it with any character it is showing full email then, I am wondering what is making this happen.

I am attaching screenshots for your reference, BTW I am using frame layout if that makes any deference.

**10 inch screen screenshot**
[image: 10 inch screen screenshot]

**7 inch screenshot with problem**
[image: 7 inch screenshot with problem]

**7 inch screenshot with replacement of @ with $ sign showing fine.**
[image: 7 inch screenshot with replacement of @ with $ sign showing fine.]

Comment: Check link :- http://www.technotalkative.com/android-show-error-in-edittext/

Comment: @InsaneCat I know how to use `setError` function, please read the problem and see screenshots for same.